# Improve scala functional string transformation

Tags: scala

How could this scala code be made more concise and/or idiomatic? Do I need to define each functions as a `val` in order to pass them as values, or is there a shorthand for this? Also looking for feedback on the `disenvowel` function.

```
// See: http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2012/04/secret-powers-of-foldleft-in-scala.html
def transformString(s: String, fns: List[Function1[String,String]]) :String =
  (s /: fns) { (s: String, f: Function1[String,String]) => f apply s }

val toUpper = (s: String) => s.toUpperCase
val reverse = (s: String) => s.reverse
val disenvowel = (s: String) => s filterNot { Set('a','e','i','o','u') contains _ }

// scala> transformString("blah",List(disenvowel))
// res175: String = blh

// scala> transformString("blah",List(disenvowel, toUpper))
// res176: String = BLH

// scala> transformString("blah",List(disenvowel, toUpper, reverse))
// res177: String = HLB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I might chime in briefly, it all looks fine, any modifications here are mostly a matter of taste and personal preference; for example, I'd make it a curried function with varargs:

```
def transformString(s : String)(functions : String => String*) = 
    functions.foldLeft(s) { (str, fun) => fun(str) }
```

And you don't need to define functions as literals, for example:

```
scala> def toUpper(s : String) = s.toUpperCase
toUpper: (s: String)String

scala> def reverse(s : String) = s.reverse
reverse: (s: String)String
```

And then, using the slightly modified version above:

```
scala> transformString("blah")(toUpper, reverse)
res3: String = HALB
```

Of course, you can always use the literal, too:

```
scala> val reverse2 = (s : String) => s.reverse
reverse2: String => String = <function1>

scala> transformString("blah")(reverse2)
res4: String = halb
```

Or even provide the lambda in-place:

```
scala> transformString("blah")(_ + "1", _.reverse)
res9: String = 1halb
```

IMO, varargs here work nicely, and you can transform any sequence/collection into varargs by `:_*`; there are a few differences, though:

1. `def` methods have to be partially applied in the list (e.g. : `toUpper_` below)
2. Underscore shorthand syntax won't work

so:

```
scala> transformString("blah ")(List(reverse2, (s : String) => s + "12", toUpper_):_*)
res21: String = " HALB12"
```

[EDIT for the comments]

1 & 2. Oh, there is a difference. You can easily make a function partially applied if it's curried, not so much if it just takes in arguments. Also, you *can* make shorthand underscore syntax work *after* applying the function partially:

```
scala> def blahArg = transformString("blah")_
blahArg: Seq[String => String] => String
```

Note the trailing underscore and the return type: a function (with lower arity). Now you can pass that function somewhere else where the second argument can be supplied. You can't do that when taking in both arguments at once. That also means that your second parameter changed from `varargs` to `Seq`, which - in turn - means you explicitly have to pass a `Seq`, `List` or something similar:

```
scala> blahArg(List(_.reverse))
res10: String = halb
```

3.Removing vowels looks fine :) If that's contained inside an `object`, you can move the `Set` initialization to the object level, so it's only initialized once instead of on every function call, but that's nitpicking.

Comment: So there's no solution for `error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.reverse)` when trying `transformString("blah", List(_.reverse))` ?

Comment: Also, is there any behavioral difference between `transformString("blah",_.toUpperCase)` and `transformString("blah")(_.toUpperCase)` - or is it just style?

Comment: Lastly, how does `disenvowel` look?

Comment: @noahz edited to address your questions :)

Comment: Thanks, I also found a better (IMO) disenvowel too: `def disenvowel (s: String) = s filterNot {Set("aeiou": _*)(_) }`

Comment: Even better: `def disenvowel (s: String) = s filterNot { "aeiouAEIOU" toSet _ }`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the function definition, you can do this inline using a function literal (which is basically a lambda):

```
transformString("blah", List(s => s.toUpperCase, s => s.reverse))
```

In fact, you can make this even more concise using `_`:

```
transformString("blah", List(_.toUpperCase, _.reverse))
```

For larger functions like `disenvowel` (which I'd probably call `removeVowels`), it'd likely be better to define it as a separate function, since it's likely less readable as a function literal. The implementation itself looks fine to me.